# Not preserving time format while exporting to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, data-export

I tried to export XML data to Excel using datasets which includes one column of 24 hr format time in my table.

Now when it is exported to Excel it is displaying in 12 hr format. I want to preserve the 24 hr format.

Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

would this not be a format issue in excel, in other words once you have finished exporting the data to excel format the cells as needed by highlighting the cells you want to change and right clicking and selecting format cells